# Excelfunction for multicriteria lookup on different rows

Tags: excel, lookup

I have data in an Excel sheet that is structured with a main category, and sub categories (persons) on the next column in the row below the main category and in the columns next to the sub categories I have qty measurements, see picture for clarification.

[image]

I need to do a lookup (for example **xlookup** or index/match) and find a specific category (yellow), and then find a specific person in that category (yellow) and return the qty numbers (green).

I've looked into multiple criteria look ups with index/match but the criteria's, as far as I understand it, need to be located on the same row for that to work. Another solution might be too find the Main category, and then return that array + the 4 rows beneath it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX`/`MATCH` for first quantity:

```
=INDEX(D:D;MATCH(1;($C:$C=$I$2)*(ROW($A:$A)>MAX(ROW($A:$A)*($A:$A=$H$2)));0))
```

for second - copy formula to the right.
In pre O365 formula must be entered as array formula with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`

[image]

Comment: Big thanks!! Works perfect! could you explain what the * sign means/does?

Comment: @Geomariachi Multiplication of bool values is equivalent to ```AND```. In this case we get array of ```0``` and ```1``` and ```MATCH``` function returns first position number that contains ```1```.